# Realm Object Server refuses to recognize permission and loads objects extremely slow

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a synchronized realm running on Realm Object Server. It is a global realm created by the admin user. I created another user on the server (not an admin) and used the admin user to grant read-only permissions to that user for that particular realm.

I can see the permission when I query the admin's management realm and the normal user's permission realm. However, when I connect to the global realm from my iOS app (Swift 3) with the normal user, the server returns error code 206: permission denied and closes the realm file.

The strange thing is that the app manages to download a few objects from the realm, and it also loads a few more objects (about 3) every time I relaunch it.

An even stranger thing is that when I launch the app with the admin user the same thing happens except it loads about 100 extra objects in every relaunch and it doesn't show the permission denied error.

**Note:** I'm getting these results on the iOS simulator and still haven't tried the app on an actual device.

**UPDATE:** I have tried the app on a physical device and the problem persists.

I'm using Realm Swift v2.10.1 on Xcode 8.3.3 and Realm Object Server v1.8.3 on a Linux Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64 machine.

**EDIT:**

Here is how I apply the permission:

```
let per = SyncPermissionValue(realmPath: "/realmname", userID: "userId", accessLevel: .read)

            realmUser!.applyPermission(per, callback: { (error) in

                print("PERMISSION ERROR: \(String(describing: error))")

                if error == nil {

                    print("no error")

                }

            })
```

Here is how connect from my app. These methods are in a custom class which is used by the view controller requesting the objects from the realm.

```
private func logInToServer() {

    SyncUser.logIn(with: .usernamePassword(username: "username", password: "pass", register: false), server: URL(string: "http://server IP:9080")!, onCompletion: { (user, error) in

        var realmUser = user
        if realmUser == nil {

            realmUser = SyncUser.current

        }

        self.connectToDatabase(realmUser: realmUser!)

    })

} // end logInToServer()

private func connectToDatabase(realmUser: SyncUser) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

        let configuration = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: realmUser, realmURL: URL(string: "realm://server IP/realmname")!))
        self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)

        // I initially found out that implementing a small delay gave the app enough time to download all objects even though the permission denied error was still there. But, this no longer works.
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: self.delay, target: self, selector: #selector(self.populateResults), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    })

} // end connectToDatabase()

@objc private func populateResults() {

    self.categories = self.realm.objects(BookCategory.self)
    self.books = self.realm.objects(Book.self)

    delegate?.didPopulteResults(categories, books) // The delegate is the view controller requesting the objects.

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more codes for this action? and when you `However, when I connect to the global realm from my iOS app (Swift 3), the server returns error code 206: permission denied and closes the realm file.`, do you use the normal user?

Comment: @aircraft I updated the question with code samples and, yes, the error appears only when using the normal (non-admin) user.

Comment: @MhdSamad Probably you hit opening a read-only Realm without asyncOpen will cause an error? https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#opening-a-synchronized-realm